# Custom STM32 board can be programmed via USB DFU, but no connection via ST-Link

Tags: stm32, schematics, microprocessor, debugging, st-link

I have spent a fair bit of time trying to understand why the stlink does not to see the STM chip when conected over serial wire (port is shown under 'Com ports' in the schematic). I have tried the st-link included on a nucleo board and a clone. I pulled the BOOT0 pin high to program over usb for a simple led blink with hse clock too and everything worked fine thankfully. I tried to make the board as simple as possible as im very early in electronics in genereal. My schematic is attached here...

[image: Schematic]

It is a STM32F446RCT6.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do, i.e. connect with ST-Link, but how? Which ST-Link module you have, original or clone, how is it connected to MCU SWD or JTAG pins? And you say connecting via COM port, but ST-Link is not a COM port so it can't be connected to via COM port.

Comment: @Justme Ive edited the question to be more clearer. Thanks. It is conected to the stlinks via mcu swd. The net name was given by the default mcu footprint, im assuming it uses the same pins for jtag and swd

Comment: I still can't figure out which pins on your debug connector you connected to (a) Nucleo ST-Link and if the original Nucleo target STM32 was still connected or only this target in your schematics, or (b) how it was connected to the clone STLink. From where was this board powered up while debugging - or was it powered up at all? So it is unknown if the connections were correct or incorrect.

Comment: Did you disconnected jumpers on ST-Link on Nucleo board which connects Nucleo MCU to the ST-Link? Otherwise you connected to two MCUs at the same time and this cant work. What Nucelo board do you use?

Comment: @Misaz i did remove the jumpers

Comment: @Justme the original nucleo had the jumper pins removed to program the custom board, the board was powered via external power source when plugged into the stlink programmer

Comment: ok, did you connect grounds of both boards?

Comment: @Misaz yep, and i connected the ground pin on the clone stm programmer too

Comment: What NUCLEO-F446RE version do you have? There are schematics for version C03, C04 and C05.

Comment: How are u powering up the custom board and the NUCLEO-F446RE stlink?

Comment: @Rodo usb, ive checked voltages and the custom stm board gets 3.3V, and runs a program fine (programmed via booloader)